# Change default event used in IBAction when linking from Storyboard to code

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, ibaction

Is it possible to change the default event a custom `UIControl` triggers when linking an `IBAction` from storyboard to code?

Let me explain:

If you add a `UIButton` in your storyboard and alt-drag it to your code, you get a popup where you can define the type of connection you want as `IBOutlet` or in this case `IBAction`.

In case you select `IBAction`, the default event that is selected is `Touch Up Inside`, which is great because the probability is big that you just want to know when the button is pressed!

[image: UIButton IBAction]

But if you do that from a custom `UIView/UIControl` or event a subclass of `UIButton`, the default event sent is always `Value Changed`

[image: Custom UIControl IBAction]

So here is my question: is it possible to change the default behaviour for a custom UI element?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the default, however...

In case you're not aware, you can right-click on UI element and click-drag from the pop-up menu for the event you want to connect.

Also, if you already have your `@IBAction` in your code, as in:

```
@IBAction func myFunc(_ sender: Any) {
    // code here
}
```

you can right-click your UI element and drag from the desired event to that function block to make the connection. The block of code will highlight letting you know you can release the mouse button.

Not quite "customizing" ctrl-drag, but you might find that easier / quicker.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag, I actually use this popup menu as well when connecting, but as you don't know which events are supported by the custom element unless you've built it yourself or checked the code I find that it's not really friendly to other developers that might work on the project after me. A good alternative otherwise though!

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean. Adding something like a `generatesEvents []` property to `@IBDesignable` classes that would control the context menu would be a nice addition to Xcode / IB.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just create an outlet for your button

```
 @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!
```

and then later add your action programatically:

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myButtonActionMethod(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and,

```
@objc func myButtonActionMethod(sender:UIButton) { 
//do something
}
```

then you'll have a bit more control. Is that what you mean?

Comment: There are a lot of alternatives indeed but I am really looking for a solution where I can still make use the alt-drag functionality of Xcode and not have to open the dropdown.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean